# Notice: Undefined index: room_image

Tags: php, mysql

I am receiving this error : Notice: Undefined index: room_image in C:\wamp64\www\iznajmi\tbaraj.php on line 80 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0636257880{main}( )...\tbaraj.php:0 " />
Garden view

$ 100

( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: room_image in C:\wamp64\www\iznajmi\tbaraj.php on line 86 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation 10.0636257880{main}( )...\tbaraj.php:0 " class="img-responsive" />

and I realized this section of code in the file is wrong, however I'm not that great in PHP yet and I am wondering if someone can help me  to eliminate the error. Thanks! 
Here is the code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","iznajmi");
if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"])){
    if(isset($_SESSION["iznajmi"]))
    {
        $item_array_id=array_column($_SESSION["iznajmi"],"room_id");
        if(!in_array($_GET["room_id"], $item_array_id))
        {
            $count=count($_SESSION["iznajmi"]);
            $item_array=array(
            'room_id'                =>$_GET["room_id"],
            'room_type'              =>$_POST["hidden_name"],
            'room_price'             =>$_POST["hidden_price"],
            'room_image'             =>$_FILES["room_image"]
            );
            $_SESSION["iznajmi"][$count]=$item_array;
        }
         else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("Already Added") </script>';
            echo '<script>window.location="tbaraj.php"</script>';
        }
    }

    else
    {
        $item_array=array(
        'room_id'                =>$_GET["room_id"],
        'room_type'              =>$_POST["hidden_type"],
        'room_price'             =>$_POST["hidden_price"]

        );
        $_SESSION["iznajmi"][0]=$item_array;
    }

}
 if(isset($_GET["action"]))  
 {  
      if($_GET["action"] == "delete")  
      {  
           foreach($_SESSION["iznajmi"] as $keys => $values)  
           {  
                if($values["room_id"] == $_GET["room_id"])  
                {  
                     unset($_SESSION["iznajmi"][$keys]);  
                     echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';  
                     echo '<script>window.location="tbaraj.php"</script>';  
                }  
           }  
      }  
 }  

?>


<html>

<head> 
<title>Барај</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
<h3 align="center">Изнајми Me | Барај ..</h3> <br  />
<?php

$query="SELECT *FROM roomtype ORDER BY room_id ";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<div class="col-md-4">
     <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="index.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["room_id"]; ?> ">
       <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="">
          <img src="<?php echo  $row["room_image"]; ?>" />
           <h4 class="text-info"> <?php echo $row["room_type"]; ?> </h4>
          <h4 class="text-info"> $ <?php echo $row["room_price"];  ?> </h4>



          <img src="<?php echo $row["room_image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br /> 
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_type"  value="<?php echo $row["room_type"]; ?>"   /> 
          <input type="hidden" name="hidden_location" value="<?php echo $row["room_price"]; ?>"/>
          <input type="submit" name="view_details"    value="view_details" class="btn btn-info btn-xs" />
          <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart"   style="margin-top:3px" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" value="Wanna book" />

      </div>
     </form>
    </div>      
<?php   
    };
};
?>
```

and here is also my `roomtype` table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `roomtype` (
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `room_type` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `room_price` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `room_seson` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `room_picture` varchar(100) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`)
);



INSERT INTO `roomtype` (`room_id`, `room_type`, `room_price`, `room_seson`) VALUES
(1, 'Garden view', '100', 'low season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/room4.jpg' ),
(2, 'Garden view', '200', 'high season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/room1.jpg' ),
(3, 'Street view', '45', 'low season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/soba1/soba101.jpg' ),
(4, 'Street view', '90', 'high season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/soba1/soba102.jpg'),
(5, 'Ocean view', '250', 'low season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/soba1/soba10.jpg'),
(6, 'Ocean view', '500', 'high season', '/C:/wamp64/www/iznajmi/images/soba1/soba104.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of code like this:

```
$item_array=array(
            'room_id'                =>$_GET["room_id"],
            'room_type'              =>$_POST["hidden_name"],
            'room_price'             =>$_POST["hidden_price"],
            'room_image'             =>(isset($_FILES["room_image"])) ? $_FILES["room_image"] : null // here
                );
```